# Why can we multiply by $dt/dt$ to change variable of integration? Please look at equation 5-20

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, work, integration, calculus

I am struggling to understand why can we just multiply by $dt/dt$. I was thinking it was just a change of variables, but I cannot come up how that works. Can someone explain why we are allowed to do this?

[image]

Comment: Also check: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572956/the-usage-of-chain-rule-in-physics/573232#573232

Comment: No where is there a multiplication by dt/dt.  Please clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x=x(t)$ being a function of time, we can compute it's total differential:

$$dx = \frac{dx}{dt}dt$$ and thus,

$$\int f(x)dx = \int f(x(t))\frac{dx}{dt}dt$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Now, what if it was a definite integral? lets say from x=1 to x=5, how do we change the limits of integration?

Comment: you need to invert your equation for $x(t)=1$ to get at which $t$ you have $x=1$.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense! thank you!

Comment: @BaLalo if this answer suits you don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer ; )